# Expanding pictures which won't re-arrange layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a photo gallery.  When the user hovers over a photo, it tilts to the side and becomes slightly bigger.  However, on certain viewport-widths, this can cause the photos to awkwardly re-arrange themselves.  How can I avoid this?  How can I make it so that if a photo spills over the edge, everything still stays in a single row, and perhaps the excess just gets cut off.  I've tried using the overflow property and the flexbox, at least the options which seemed to make sense like `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

```
    img {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img:hover {
  border-color: yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 225px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 12px gray;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  
}
```

Comment: Don't change the size, use a scale transform instead.

Comment: That doesn't work :(

Comment: Sure it does. It's the only way to avoid a layout change.